# Deploy WebApp - Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform not Loaded?

Tags: c#, asp.net

create a Blank WebApplication in Visual Studio Community 2017 rel. 15.3.5
next added WebForm
target asp.net 4.6.1 (but also with 4.5 is the same problem)

Updated Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompiler at v1.0.7
and Microsoft.Net.Compiler at v.2.3.2

when start /domain/Test2/WebForm1.aspx i have this error

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
```

why Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform not Loaded ?
the folder bin is present on Server => domain/Test2/bin

Assembly binding logging is turned OFF ???
the end user do not modify registry

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title></title>
</head>
 <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    </div>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

the WebForm1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
  public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this in debug or are you deploying to a clean VM with IIS on it?

Comment: I am using a Windows Hosting provider

Comment: It looks like it doesn't have .NET installed on it